# How to solve $y = 2^z / x$, where $x,y,z \in \mathbb{N}$ , without using actual division.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to develop a piece of software to find a ratio between two natural numbers $2^z$ and $x$.  This involves a function to solve the (simple linear) equation below.

$$f(x)\{ f,x,z \in \mathbb{N} \} = \lfloor{2^z / x}\rfloor $$
Where:
$$2^{20} < x < 2^{32},0 < y < 2^{32},2^{31} < z < 2^{64} \text{, and z is a constant.}$$

Is there some function (or algorithm) $f'(x) = f(x)$ that does not use division?

In the context of it being a software problem, $2^z$ is a single-bit binary number (0x4000) multiplied by $2^{31}$ (shifted left by 31 places) so that the result is accurate to 32 binary digits.

I originally posted a software-specific question ([Trick to divide a constant (power of two) by an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35063224/3581917)) on Stack Overflow and received several comments that have led me to look at multiplicative inverses and Euler's totient function.  However, since the majority of values of $z$ will not be coprime with a given value of $2^z$, these do not appear to be applicable.

Comment: In any solution $x$ must be a power of $2$, so you can express it as $y = 2^{z-\log_2{x}}$ where $\log_2{x}$ is also an integer, does that help?

Comment: @DanBrumleve It does help, in as much as it indicates that my question is wrong.  I should have used something other than the = operator, as what I really want is the nearest approximate, rather than restricting the domain of x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look at your original SO question, and you formulated your math question wrong:

you want to solve for $y$ in $y=\lfloor2^z/x\rfloor$ where $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ is the mathematical notation for the $\mathrm{floor}$ function that rounds down to the nearest integer and $z=2^{32}\cdot 16384=2^{46}$ (not $z\approx2^{2^{46}}$ as you formulated your question). Unfortunately, there is no clever solution for division with an *arbitrary divisor*. Your need to compute long division, which is an iterative process, and the special structure of $2^z$ gets lost after the first iteration. There are tricks for constant divisiors or divisors with a special structure, but not for the general case.